# How do I get my svg clock arms to correspond with the current time using GSAP?

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

I have to make an analog clock for a school project, and one of my teachers suggested I use an svg image to design the clock. A condition of the project was that we can ONLY use GSAP to build the thing, so no jQuery or anything else.

I have gotten all three arms to move in a way I like, so the only thing left to do is getting it to show the current time, but I just have no idea where to begin.

Can anyone on here tell me how this is done?

My code is shown below.

Thanks!

```js
 TweenMax.to("#sec", 60, {
  rotation: 360,
  ease:SteppedEase.config(60),
  transformOrigin:"left 50%",
  repeat:-1,});
 TweenMax.to("#min", 3600, {
  rotation: 360,
  ease:Linear.
  easeNone,
  transformOrigin:"left 50%",
  reapeat:-1})
 TweenMax.to("#hour", 43200, {
  rotation: 360,
  ease:Linear.easeNone,
  transformOrigin:"left 50%",
  reapeat:-1})
```

```html
<div class="main">

      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="197.99999999999997" height="197.99999999999997" id="clock">

       <g>
        <title>Layer 1</title>
        <ellipse ry="98.333335" rx="98.333335" id="svg_2" cy="99.083343" cx="99.083342" stroke-width="1.5" fill="#DDDDDD"/>
        <ellipse ry="3.888889" rx="3.888889" id="svg_4" cy="99.480005" cx="98.844871" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#000000" fill="#000000"/>
        <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_5" y2="29.011012" x2="98.679308" y1="9.487236" x1="98.679308" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_6" y2="188.952263" x2="98.881328" y1="169.428488" x1="98.881328" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(90 179.04959106445315,99.25782012939455) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_7" y2="109.019706" x2="179.04958" y1="89.495931" x1="179.04958" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(90 18.535934448242177,99.25782012939455) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_8" y2="109.019706" x2="18.535938" y1="89.495931" x1="18.535938" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(30 138.88128662109378,30.191871643066396) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_9" y2="39.953759" x2="138.881277" y1="20.429984" x1="138.881277" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(60 168.30883789062497,59.24907684326173) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_10" y2="69.010961" x2="168.30885" y1="49.487185" x1="168.30885" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(120 168.342529296875,139.6281280517578) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_11" y2="149.390025" x2="168.342523" y1="129.86625" x1="168.342523" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(150 138.88128662109372,168.65167236328122) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_12" y2="178.413558" x2="138.881281" y1="158.889782" x1="138.881281" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(30 58.847702026367244,168.71022033691406) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_14" y2="178.4721" x2="58.847705" y1="158.948325" x1="58.847705" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(60 29.42013549804691,139.4173126220703) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_15" y2="149.179211" x2="29.420132" y1="129.655435" x1="29.420132" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(120 29.58848571777344,59.42621612548828) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_16" y2="69.188104" x2="29.588483" y1="49.664328" x1="29.588483" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(150 58.881378173828125,30.166999816894524) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_17" y2="39.928887" x2="58.88138" y1="20.405112" x1="58.88138" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(150 138.88128662109372,168.65167236328122) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_18" y2="178.413558" x2="138.881281" y1="158.889782" x1="138.881281" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
        <line transform="rotate(150 138.88128662109372,168.65167236328122) " stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_19" y2="178.413558" x2="138.881281" y1="158.889782" x1="138.881281" fill-opacity="null" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>

        <g id="min">
         <line stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_20" y2="9.365203" x2="99.308956" y1="100.647963" x1="99.308956" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
         <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_21" y2="99.93648" x2="99.308956" y1="188.933524" x1="99.308956" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="3" fill="none"/>
        </g>

        <g id="hour">
         <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_23" y2="99.763148" x2="98.900288" y1="51.17836" x1="98.900288" fill-opacity="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none"/>
         <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_24" y2="148.335333" x2="98.900288" y1="99.750546" x1="98.900288" fill-opacity="null" stroke-width="5" fill="none"/>
        </g>

        <g id="sec">
         <line stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_26" y2="9.936631" x2="98.737529" y1="101.219391" x1="98.737529" stroke-opacity="null" fill="none"/>
         <line stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" id="svg_27" y2="100.507907" x2="98.737529" y1="189.504951" x1="98.737529" stroke-opacity="null" fill="none"/>
        </g>
       </g>

      </svg>

    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.1.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Edit: GSAP is the GreenSock Animation Platform